# DropDownList Dependencies and Selections Using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 6 dropdownlist as shown below:

```
option1
option2

option3
option4

option5
option6
```

When I change option1 I want to change option3 and option5. When I change option2 I want to change option4 and option6. These list can be in any number. Here is another example:

```
option1
option2
option3

option4
option5
option6

option7
option8
option9
```

Now when I change option1 then option4 and option7 will change. When I chanage option5 then option2 and option8 will change. When I change option9 then option6 and option3 will change. I think u can see the pattern.

I solved part of the problem by assigning same classes to related options. But sometimes the data is coming from database and I cannot assign classes since I don't know which options are in group.

If I move all these options in an array then how can I make dependencies between them?

Comment: be a lot simpler to resolve if you show some html hierarchy, and define what changing #1 does to #4

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a function to each option that will be triggered by the "change" event and will change some other options.